# Find the unique degree $6$ polynomial

Tags: polynomials

What makes it unique is the following requirements on the polynomial:

1. It's coefficients are either $0$ or $1$
2. It has no rational roots
3. The absolute value of $p(x)$ isn't prime for every integer.

Just for this problem, $1$ isn't a prime.

Comment: "Just for this problem, 1 isn't a prime." -- $1$ has never been a prime number.

Comment: you tried something

Comment: @Glacier: Not true.  $1$ was considered prime up to Henri Lebesgue's time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here it is: $$f(x)=x^6+x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+1)(x^4+1)$$

It's also even, so $f(x)=f(-x)$.  We get $f(0)=1$, and $f(n)$ has two factors greater than $1$ for $n \geq 1$ due to the polynomial's factorization.

---

To prove it's unique:

- The coefficient of $x^6$ is $1$, otherwise it doesn't have degree $6$.  The constant term is $1$, otherwise it has root $0$.
- It must have $4$ non-zero coefficients (otherwise $f(1) \in \{2,3,5\}$, and $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ evaluated at $x=1$ gives $7$ (which is prime)).
- What's left has $f(-1) \in \{0,2\}$ (giving either a root or a prime) except for the above polynomial.

Comment: Very well argued indeed! +1!